# javascript convert date in the future to timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I want to get the timestamp of one-year from now:

```
var oneYr = new Date();
oneYr.setYear((new Date()).getYear() + 1);
```

When I try to get the timestamp:

```
oneYr.getTime() /1000
```

I get `-58351759111000` (not correct)

It's only working for date in the past.
Any idea how to get timestamp for future date?

Answer (score 0):

Use getFullYear instead of getYear.

```
var oneYr = new Date();
oneYr.setYear((new Date()).getFullYear() + 1);
```

Comment: This should use the *setFullYear* method. The brackets around `(new Date())` are redundant. Also need to deal with 29 Feb + 1 year. It will roll over to 1 Mar, which may nor may not suit.